# flash as3 - one video object, multiple video files

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, netstream

I have one video object and 3 thumbnails which, when clicked, will play different video files. What is the best practice for this situation?

Currently I have one net connection, one net stream, and one video object. When a thumbnail is clicked, I just say ns.pause(), then ns.play(video2.flv). This sort of works, except if I play video1.flv, then video2.flv, then play video1.flv again, it gets all scrambled - the video plays but is chopped up with ugly lines across it.

Comment: ns.close() seems to help. I'd still like to hear ideas on best practices for this situation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling [ns.close()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#close%28%29) before ns.play() should reset the stream for another use.